# Answer truncated

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/551992/1835769) is the first answer to a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/551892/1835769).

I'm not sure how you guys are seeing it but on my machine this answer looks like this (Note how the answer ends abruptly):

[image]

When I tried to see the exact content of the answer and clicked on 'edit' button, I saw the non-truncated (and probably even complete) version of the answer.

What is happening here?

Comment: Do you see the correct content now?  I do.

Comment: Maybe the person [died while writing it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlIz0q8aWpA).

Comment: @NathanOliver: I do now, after 2 refreshes since the last comment. Care to explain what happened?

Comment: Probably seeing a cached version.  Someone edited it just now so you should see the updated version.

Comment: I removed the broken image.

Comment: For the people who are going there and reading the question/answers, the answer by @JamesJones is hillarious.

Comment: I'm not seeing any truncation - neither in the edit history nor on the main post.

Comment: @Makoto Mike made an edit to remove a broken image which fixed the problem. Only thing to do now is wait for an explanation of why that syntax caused the rendering issue.

Comment: @Makoto: In the edit history, the answer looks fine. Only when you save it the same way it originally was (i.e. without Mike's edits) do you see the truncation.

Comment: @gunr2171: Sounds plausible. (Just now saw the video).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a short-lived rendering bug (when converting from markdown to HTML) that was around when that answer was posted.

That is what caused the truncation. The bug was fixed very shortly after being introduced, but there were a few posts affected, just like the one you noted.

Given that we save the rendered HTML together with the markdown on a post and do not regenerate it unless the post has changed, the incorrect HTML was never re-rendered and the post was truncated.

As soon as someone edited the post, the HTML got regenerated, sans bug.